# How do i change a listview on activity resume?

Tags: java, android

I have a ListView of database items in my main activity, in my main activity i have a method that populates the list view from my database that runs on the oncreate of the main method.

from my main activity the user can go into the menu and click on something called "change view" which is an activity that lets the user change the search criteria for the database, I then have a method that populates the listview from this search criteria.

After the user clicks on the change view button within this activity i want the application to then go back to the main activity and to display this new custom list view, my first thought was to call this method in the on resume, but that doesn't work for the obvious reasons, would appreciate any direction.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `startActivityForResult` from your main activity or the activity with the list to call the change view activity and then pass the selected option back to the calling activity and use the `onActivityResult` to read the data returned 
and then populate the listview based on it

this [link](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example) will give you a starting point.or you can use the [official reference](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom broadcast receiver for that like below

When you click on the button write this code

```
Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN")
        this.sendBroadcast(i);
finish()//finish your current button activity if this is an activity
```

Now in onResume of listview activity

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
                "android.intent.action.MAIN");
        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // Update you listview

            }
        };
        //registering our receiver
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
```

And in onPause you must unregister the receiver like below code

```
this.unregisterReceiver(this.mReceiver);
```